# Setting onClickListener to AlertDialog ListView

Tags: android, actionlistener, android-alertdialog

I am trying to set up an onClickListener to my ListView in my AlertDialog, but I keep getting errors.

When using this code I get an error under "setOnClickListener" stating `The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){})`

Here's my code, hopefully someone could help me out, thanks.

```
            String names[] ={"A","B","C","D"};
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.customdialog, null);
        alertDialog.setView(convertView);
        alertDialog.setTitle("List");
        ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        alertDialog.show();


        lv.setOnClickListener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                switch(which){


                case 0:

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "clicked 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    break;


                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: what you want is `onItemClickListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OnItemClickListener`. There is param (third one) `int position` which gives you the index of list item click. Based on index you can do what you want.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    {
      switch(position){
       case 0:

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "clicked 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    } 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead on Dialog.OnClickListener you need to use [View.OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)

Do the following changes:

```
lv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(which){


        case 0:

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "clicked 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            break;


        }

    }
});
```